# Symfony Twig Translation does not fill in placeholders

Tags: symfony, twig

I am currently having the situation where a twig-filtered string that contains placeholders does only translate the string itself but does not respect the available, and linked, placeholders.

My example:

```
{{ 'this is my test: %test%'|trans({'%test%': 'test!'|trans}) }}
```

I have the translation available in my XLF file (automatically generated by symfony), lets say I add `__` as prefixex to the string. I clear the cache and reload, and I do see that the string itself get translated, but now, instead of:

```
__this is my test: __test!
```

The string looks like this:

```
__this is my test: %test%
```

In other words, it does not seem to insert the placeholder as expected.

Why? The placeholder translation works however, if I remove the original translation for the parent string. So, only one does work:

- translate the parent string
- place the placeholder correctly

But not both at the same time.

The template where I am using this is included by another template. Is this maybe an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default engine of translator isn't enough smart to do it, and there is a lot of confusions with word between `%` like `%test%`. To translate sentences like yours, you should use the ICU format. [Here is an article about the ICU format and Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html)

You can fix it in a few steps:

1. Surround the parameter with `{` `}` in the sentence to translate:

```
{{ 'this is my test: {test}'|trans({'test': 'test!'|trans}) }}
```

2. Tell to symfony your using the ICU format by adding the good extension on your translation file. As example, rename your file from `messages.yaml` to `messages+intl-icu.en.yaml`
3. Clear your cache
4. Report modifications to your `messages+intl-icu.en.yaml` file.

```yaml
# translations/messages+intl-icu.en.yaml
test!: '__test!'
"this is my test: {test}": '__this is my test: {test}'
```

Be aware on the non-translated parameter in translated sentence! Keep in mind that {test} shall NOT be translated because it will be replace by value **after** the translation process.
In your code, the process is:

1. translate `test!` to `__test!`
2. translate `this is my test: {test}` to `__this is my test: {test}`
3. replace `{test}` by `__test!`

Result becomes like you expected it:
`__this is my test: __test!`

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer, so community won't loose to time by reading your resolved question :) Thank you

Comment: Sure. How could I forget about it? :D